# Use `across()` to create new columns with a function of multiple other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, mutate, across

Is it possible to create multiple new columns based on a pattern of column names, and a function of multiple column values?

For example

```
set.seed(123)
tibble(x = seq(1:10), bm_a = runif(10), val_a = runif(10), bm_b = runif(10), val_b = runif(10)) |>
  mutate(rel_a = val_a - bm_a, rel_b = val_b - bm_b)
```

```
# A tibble: 10 × 7
       x   bm_a  val_a  bm_b  val_b  rel_a   rel_b
   <int>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1 0.288  0.957  0.890 0.963   0.669  0.0735
 2     2 0.788  0.453  0.693 0.902  -0.335  0.209 
 3     3 0.409  0.678  0.641 0.691   0.269  0.0502
 4     4 0.883  0.573  0.994 0.795  -0.310 -0.199 
 5     5 0.940  0.103  0.656 0.0246 -0.838 -0.631 
 6     6 0.0456 0.900  0.709 0.478   0.854 -0.231 
 7     7 0.528  0.246  0.544 0.758  -0.282  0.214 
 8     8 0.892  0.0421 0.594 0.216  -0.850 -0.378 
 9     9 0.551  0.328  0.289 0.318  -0.224  0.0290
10    10 0.457  0.955  0.147 0.232   0.498  0.0845
```

But imagine I have this for many different dynamically named columns all starting with `bm_*` and `val_*`. Is it possible to use some combination of `mutate()`, `across()`, `pick()`, `starts_with()` etc to get this to work for all possible column names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with across and pick:

```
library(tidyverse)
df |> mutate(across(starts_with("val"), ~ .x - pick(str_replace(cur_column(), "val", "bm")), .names = "{str_replace(.col, 'val', 'rel')}"))
```

But it seems probable that using pivot_longer() is a faster and more robust approach:

```
df |> 
  pivot_longer(-x, names_to = c(".value", "group"), names_pattern = "(bm|val)_(.+)") |>
  mutate(rel = val - bm)
```

More details:

1. cur_column() gets the current column name. So `str_replace(cur_column(), "val", "bm")` gets the current column name with val replaced by bm.
2. .names sets the names of the output columns. If we didn't do this, they'd overwrite the val columns!
3. the reason for the curly brackets is because of the glue syntax. across needs strings for names. Check out the glue package for more information on how this works.

Comment: the pivot approach is much simpler to understand. Probably need change the names pattern to `"(bm|val)_(.+)"` and I added the final `pivot_wider` on my end

Comment: @ChechyLevas I added the `.+` idea. In principle, it's bad to encode information in column names (google tidy data for more info). I don't know what's going on in your actual data, but I would caution against doing that kind of thing, if that is the case